# Pictures are not found from JAR built with Ant

Tags: ant, jar

I build my JAR with Ant and all the sounds and pictures and class files are included in their right directories. I however get errors like `java.io.FileNotFoundException: sounds\flipTile.wav` (The system cannot find the path specified) when I run the JAR. These errors do not occur when the project is executed from Eclipse. Why does this happen?

Comment: its depends on from where you are running ant. See that from your current directory (from where you run ant) whether sounds folder exists?

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work! I placed the JAR on the project root, where there is a directory called sounds. But the sounds directory is included in the JAR. Should I really have to do this? Shouldn't Java find the resources in the JAR, no matter on which directory I place the JAR? I need to deliver the JAR to the customer, which wants to start the JAR from anywhere. This is how my JAR looks like: -group -images -META INF - sounds. The sounds directory is included in the JAR, as you can see here.